# find specified percentage with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find the percentage of an integer in jquery:
there is a variable with different values that gets based on the selected attribute (for example the variable could have the value 0.27)

is there a already made function to find the `6.61375661375662%` of that value `(0.27)`? or do  I need to manualy write the formula?

Comment: I think you'll have to do it the **hard** way, `val * 6.61375661375662/100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var percentage = your_var * .0661375661375662;
```

or (for clarity):

```
var percentage = your_var * 6.61375661375662 / 100;
```

Comment: I am going to do it like your second example thank you for your help

Comment: Too much mathematics. Dang numbers!

Comment: @Dave Just for you, I'll try to use more pictures next time. ;)